# How to query how many processes has a page mapped?

Tags: c, posix, mmap

I have a pointer returned by `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED`. Is there a way to query the kernel for how many processes are currently mapping the pointed page?

Preferably in a portable POSIX way, but also interested in Linux and macOS.

Comment: I know that in linux `/proc/<pid>/maps` contains a list of all mapped memory segments for a process, so maybe try parsing the file?

Comment: You can probably use [lsof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) (available on linux and most BSD-derived unix systems) to do this amongst its many options, or at least show who has the file or device mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a pointer returned by mmap with MAP_SHARED. Is there a way to query the kernel for how many processes are currently mapping the pointed page?

None that I'm aware of.  This is part of the kernel internals and changes so quickly normally that makes impossible to have an efficient interface that allows you to query it reliably, not beeing for debugging purposes.

Worse, if you want it to be POSIX portable.  You need to read the POSIX document for that.  Look for it at [The Open Group](https://publications.opengroup.org/)